# Veracrypt Hidden Partition Error

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, mount, veracrypt, hidden-file

I accidentally mounted the normal volume (10Gb) and moved some files into there (~15Gb). The hidden partition is 50Gb, and when I try to mount now it is giving me an error:

> "You need to format the disk in Drive I: before you can use it. Do you
> want to format it?"

From what I've read I understand that it's possible I corrupted some of the key header data, which is now making my data unreadable, but I believe that the data is still there, since the partition still mounted. What should I do to recover? I have no experience in this and am not a technical user :(

Comment: Hi what is the size of the physical disk, and what is the partition table like, i.e. what are the partitions on the disk and what sizes are they

Comment: @avia The volume is on a harddrive. The HDD itself is 1.5TB, the volume is 60GB total, with 10GB normal volume and 50GB hidden volume

Answer (score 0):

Please be aware that I am not using Veracrypt but I know its predecessor Truecrypt.

> From what I've read I understand that it's possible I corrupted some of the key header data,

You are wrong and you could have simply found this out by reading the Truecrypt/Veracrypt manual. As this is outlined in a picture in there, no special computer knowledge is required!

Unfortunately you erased the first 5 GB of your hidden partition in case you did not protect your hidden partition using the appropriate checkbox in the mount options dialogue. Assuming this worst case the recovery work now consists in reading out the full unencrypted partly logically dammaged partition by means of addressing the new Truecrypt assigned drive letter in a windows system (you have successfully hidden the operating system you are using) as a source. The target could be a simple file for instance.

If you copied the content of the unencrypted drive into a file, some recovery programs might have difficulties because they might expect a drive image which usually starts with a partition table.

Therefore I would get a clean drive and partition it with just one partition without formating that partition.
In a next step I would copy that extracted file into the empty partition.

If this all sounds to difficult to you, consult a professional recovery service.